# Find formula across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, formula, array-formulas

I have a workbook that has multiple sheets (all formatted the same). I want to find the total of each item used for each department.

I've tried pivot tables.
I've tried consolidated tables.
I've tried SUMIf, Countif, Indirect tables.

`=SUMIF('Steven Bradley:Adam Cockroft'!A3:N31,B2,'Steven Bradley:Adam Cockroft'!N4:N31)`

> Value# errors, Ref# errors

Comment: https://exceljet.net/formula/3d-sumif-for-multiple-worksheets maybe.

Comment: Hard to help if we don't know what your data looks like. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help you improve your question

Comment: Is the *single* sheet name actually `Steven Bradley:Adam Cockroft`? Or are you trying to reference *two* sheets with that?

Comment: I don't think the functionality will work with sumif.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that formula would even work on a single sheet... your columns/rows look misaligned.

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax for going across sheets is correct, the issue is just sumif doesn't cross sheets. Similar with other array-ish functions.

The most sensible answer to me would be to do the SUMIF on each sheet, then sum.

I think the best option would be to do the SUMIF on the worksheets somewhere, then sum them up using the approach you have.

If you were insistent on doing without this approach, you could use this UDF. I don't really like it as it doesn't capture changes to other sheets, even with application.volatile.

```
Function sumifAcrossSheets(addressRng1 As Range, _
    conditionToCount As Variant, _
            sumRng As Range) As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
     sumifAcrossSheets = sumifAcrossSheets + _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf( _
            ws.Range(addressRng1.Address), _
            conditionToCount, _
            ws.Range(sumRng.Address))
    Next ws


End Function
```

Here's some notes I had lying around on this process (ignore the snarky comments:

[image]